# bootstrap toggle-switch not working on table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

i have a table with toggle switches, and i need them to be on or off according to the state i get on another column. Thing is i can't make it work, because the buttons are all disabled except the first one and the toggle is always off, no matter the state i'm getting.

Here's the stackblitz of what i'm currently trying: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aje3j9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `id="{{item}}"` and bind the item for the id

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="align-middle text-center">Agencia</th>
              <th class="align-middle text-center">Flag</th>
              <th class="align-middle text-center">Estado</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of flagEstadoAll; let item = index;" class="btn-off">
              <td class="align-middle text-center">{{data.nombre_comercial}}</td>
              <td class="align-middle text-center">{{data.nombre}}</td>
              <td class="align-middle text-center">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="item">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="item">{{data.estado_flag == 'Activo' ? 'Desactivar' : 'Activar'}}</label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it should be work

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot. Also, another question, how can i bind the toggle to the state? For example, the state says active, so the switch should be on, if inactive should be off.

Comment: use [checked]="true" or  [checked]="false"